# How to add child instance foreign key IDs as a serializer list field idiomatically?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a many-to-many model like `Request` ← `RequestItem` → `Item`, and I want the response from the `Request` API endpoint to include a list of `Item` IDs. I've got a working serializer method like this:

```
def to_representation(self, instance: Request) -> typing.Dict[str, Any]:
    representation: Dict = super().to_representation(instance)
    representation["items"] = [
        item_id for item_id
        in instance.requestitems_set.values_list("item_id", flat=True)
    ]
    return representation
```

As you can see, this is horrible. What would be an idiomatic way of getting the exact same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be added quite straightforward like any other field in the serializer

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....
    items = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        source='requestitems_set',
        slug_field='item_id',
        read_only=True,
        many=True,
    )
```

And then of course add it to the list of fields

Comment: Nice! I always thought the slug was some sort of hash of the value; never realized you could simply pull out a value this way.

Answer (score 1):

from given info, you could reduce the use of ***`for` loop*** as

```
def to_representation(self, instance: Request) -> typing.Dict[str, Any]:
    representation: Dict = super().to_representation(instance)
    representation["items"] = list(instance.requestitems_set.values_list("item_id", flat=True))
    return representation
```

Comment: changed to `list(instance.requestitems_set.values_list("item_id", flat=True))` (to `list`) @l0b0

Answer (score 1):

There are few [related fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) implemented by DRF. But API is open for you to implement your own one. I think this is more readable and clean solution.

```
class ItemIdRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        pass
        # implement if you need it.

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.item_id
```

And use it as field in serializer like this.

```
items = ItemIdRelatedField(many=True, source='requestitems_set', queryset=RequestItem.objects.all())
```